# Disable or hide Paypal on specific store view

Tags: paypal, ce-1.8.1.0, payment-methods

I want to use Paypal on English store view but not on some other store view.

How to make disable or hide Paypal on specific store view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two way to ,you can do this

### formula 1: Module Disable

`Disable` paypal  module from `Admin>System>Configuration` `Change` the `Scope to English store view` then goes to `Advance >Advance Disable Paypal  Module`.

### Formula 2: using event observer

Create an event on `payment_method_is_active` and depends on current store disable and enable payment method.

And you need change on observer.In below example i have `disable payment zero subtotal check when current store code  is English`.

```
<?php
    class Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod_Model_Observer {

    public function filterpaymentmethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
            /* call get payment method */
        $method = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

    /* this condition prevent zero payment to display when current store is english */
        if($method->getCode()=='free' &&  Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode()=='YOUR_ENGLISG STORE_CODe'){
            $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();   
            $result->isAvailable = false;
            }
        }
        return;
      }
    }
```

.

Comment: Formula 1 is not work. I disable paypal as you mention for only the store view, but still checkout can process with paypal on that store. I will try later  formula 2 if possible Thanks