# How to disable Paypal from just one of the stores in a multi-store setup?

Tags: multistore, paypal, payment-methods

I have Magento 1.9.1 with Paypal Payments Pro (Includes Express Checkout) and Express Checkout. I don't see how to disable those in just one of the stores? When I switch to the Configuration scope for the other store - it does not give me the option to disable it...Any ideas? :-*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, but it depends on the way your multi-store is setup.

From the fact that you can't disable the PayPal payment method I conclude that you are running a multi-store setup with storeviews. As far as I know standard Magento functionality does not allow you to disable/enable payment methods on a storeview level.

When your store is configured with multiple websites you should be able to disable/enable payment methods on a per-website level.

Some alternatives based on creating modules are presented here:
[How to restrict payment methods by store?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36883/how-to-restrict-payment-methods-by-store) and here: [Disable or hide Paypal on specific store view](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61613/disable-or-hide-paypal-on-specific-store-view). I have not tested these approaches though.

Comment: Why do things with Magento have to be SO difficult? Enabling Paypal on one store view and NOT the other should be a common feature! I looked at the links you gave me but I don't understand the technical mumbo-jumbo - there is not even a reference to a file to edit... :-( I disabled Paypal and Paypal UK in the Advanced in Configuration, deleted all Cache and Re-indexed but it did not help....Is there a simple way to do this? Like do STEP 1, then STEP 2, then STEP 3 .... please

Comment: Is there a way to reconfigure my 2nd store to be "with multiple websites" as you say?

Comment: I got this now - if you have the same problem - make sure you select the actual website in the Configuration - NOT just the Store View...

Comment: Can you confirm that the problem is now fixed? :-)

Comment: yes it is - thank you Herman! Do I need to do anything else on here to mark your answer as the right one? Thank you again! ;-)

Comment: No problem, Allysin!

Answer (score 1):

In order to define multiple payment methods per store you will need to create multiple Websites per store.

Website is the container for your store that holds the shipping methods, payment methods and so on. So can have multiple stores per website that share these configurations. And you can have multiple store views per store and so on.

So in order to configure multiple payment methods per store you will need to create multiple Websites.

Assuming you created multiple websites for your store

**For Magento 2.1.9** go to Stores -> Configurations

Store View: Default -> Select your Website Code not the Store

**Example**

- Store View: Default

  - WEBSITE1 <-Select the website

    - Store Name1

      - Store View1 <- You cant make changes to payment methods here
- WEBSITE2

  - Store Name2

    - Store View2